# VPN Traffic Flow

Tags: networking, vpn

Networking amateur here. I have a Fortinet VPN client installed which I use to connect to the office network. The client also installed a virtual network adapter which I understand is the interface that all outgoing VPN traffic will use. Also the VPN we’ve set up is an SSL VPN

What I'm curious about is how outgoing traffic navigates, specifically through my computer and its network interfaces. There's a virtual adapter (vEth) and of course my physical adapter (Eth). So I performed some packet capture on each and noticed the following:

1. Outgoing traffic destined for anything other than the VPN gateway (e.g. google.com) only goes through vEth, and not through Eth.
2. The only traffic captured on Eth is traffic destined specifically for the VPN gateway. There seemed to be a constant exchange happening. I wasn’t able to make much sense of the exchange. Any clarification here would be great!

For an outgoing packet, I would’ve thought the OS would check its route table and see that the outgoing traffic is to be sent to the vEth interface. I believe then the VPN client encrypts  the message/data, checks the route table for the next hop and sends it to my Eth interface and subsequently the external network. Does this sound right?

Any clarification or thoughts on why I don’t see user-initiated traffic (http requests etc.) going out the Eth interface would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For an outgoing packet, I would’ve thought the OS would check its route table and see that the outgoing traffic is to be sent to the vEth interface. I believe then the VPN client encrypts the message/data, checks the route table for the next hop and sends it to my Eth interface and subsequently the external network. Does this sound right?

Yes, although sometimes there are other methods besides the routing table, but that's the general mechanism. The VPN client receives a list of routes during login and points them through its virtual interface.

> Any clarification or thoughts on why I don’t see user-initiated traffic (http requests etc.) going out the Eth interface would be great.

The routing table doesn't point there. While some VPN clients do additional tricks, in the most basic setup you would have a second 'default' route added through vEth – if it has a lower "metric" specified, then it will override the existing 'default via Eth' route.

You kind of *do* see the requests on Eth, but they are encrypted – nearly all VPNs provide traffic encryption and integrity as their core feature. Just as with HTTPS or SSH traffic, your packet capture tool will not be able to see through the encryption performed by VPN software.

Importantly, it's the *entire packet* that is encrypted – not just the TCP payload, but the entire IP header and payload. Every VPN is fundamentally a *tunnel,* which means the packets are encapsulated in a whole new IP header with the VPN server as the destination – the original inner destination will not be visible in a packet capture on Eth as it has been encrypted together with the rest (unless you deliberately use a protocol that doesn't involve encryption, such as plain GRE or L2TP).

So what you're seeing on Eth is all of your vEth traffic, encrypted and tunneled through the VPN server.